# encountered the symbol create oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

the below oracel procedure keeps showing me "pls-00103 encountered the symbol create" and i am not ablt to figure out why.. please help

```
create or replace procedure myproc
    (
    otherdate in varchar2
    )
    as
    mystringdate varchar2(20);

    begin
    create or replace function checkdate(givdate in varchar2) return number
    as
    givedate1 date;
    begin
    givedate1 := todate(givdate);
    return1;
    exception
    when others then 
    return 0;
    end;       

    mystringdate := ltrim(rtrim(otherdate));

    if checkdate(mystringdate,'dd-mm-yyyy')= 1 then        
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('it is a date format');         
    else        
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('it is not a date format');        
    endif        
    end myproc;
```

i tried more like \ symbol and all but not working. please help

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, you started creating a proc and then inside begin you started creating function, you need to remove create function from there. Why you want to do that?

Remove this:

```
create or replace function checkdate(givdate in varchar2) return number
    as
    givedate1 date;
    begin
    givedate1 := todate(givdate);
    return1;
    exception
    when others then 
    return 0;
    end;
```

Comment: Is there any function like isdate in sql server to check whether the variable is DATE. I thought there is no function in Oracle[correct me if I am wrong], so created a function to check whether the variable is date

Comment: You approachis coorect for what you want to do but dont need to write a function, just use a nested block. Just keep the portion between begin and end of your function and remove return statement.